# Does a set in node.js reset if you restart a program?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I made a discord bot (this has nothing to do with the library), and was planning on implementing some Sets. What worried me was that every time the code is loaded, it sets the variable which my set is in to have no values. Does anyone know if this happens, and if it does, how to stop it from happening?

Comment: If you wish to keep data between runs of your program you need to save it in persistant storage of some kind like a database or external cache like redis.

Comment: Unless you implement some sort of permanent storage (a database integration, or reading/writing a file) all values will be ephemeral... after all, there is nothing they could be persisted in! A process exists in RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your program restarts, any memory the old program was keeping is freed and your code re-allocates everything from a clean slate (mostly).

What you need is **persistence**. This means storing data on disk. Generally, you'll want some kind of database, whether RDBMS or NoSQL, but I encourage you to explore other options as well - without knowing your use case there is not really a useful recommendation to make.

Comment: @HRashid For a discord bot, it depends on how much you want to be prepared for scalability. When your bot gets on many servers, you will eventually find it necessary to split the one bot into many processes - in such an occasion, `fs` or `sqlite` will fail to be useful (they don't well support multiple concurrent reads/writes). I personally use postgreSQL and love it. But if your bot will only be on one or a small handful of servers, feel free to use either of those as they will be easier to use.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it out, and let you know.

Comment: Im not sure what fs is but sqlite is great for setting up smaller test projects. If you have a larger project with many users you might want to concider using a databse more like mysql, postgres or sqlserver.

Comment: @Achtung `fs` is the default filesystem module for node.js - I guess it implies just some plaintext or JSON persistence.